# Webpack sass more specific sourcemaps

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm trying to get more specific sourcemaps from my scss files with webpack.

Pretend I have this example.scss

```
1. .parent {
2.    font-size: 10px;
3.
4.    .child {
5.        font-size: 15px;
6.    }
7. }
```

And I'm inspecting on `<div class="child"></div>` I see that this:

```
.parent .child {         example.scss:1
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Is there a way to point it to example.scss:4 ?

I'm still googlin' but doesn't hurt to ask since I havn't found it yet, right? :)

My webpack config:

```
{
    entry: function() {
        ...
    },
    output: {
        ...
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    esModule: false,
                    loaders: {
                        scss: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    sourceMap: true,
                                    url: false,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                loader: 'sass-loader',
                                options: {
                                    sourceMap: true,
                                    url: false,
                                },
                            }],
                            fallback: 'vue-style-loader?sourceMap',
                        }),
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        ...
    },
    plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/[name].css')],
    devtool: 'module-source-map',
}
```

Comment: What version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: @brianespinosa I'm using 3.12.0